# Simple API Post with HttpClient

Tags: c#, post, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to get a balance from coinfloor using their API,
while I was able to successfully parse their unauthenticated/public GET responses, I'm having troubles sending authenticated private POST requests with extra parameters.

Currently I get StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static void Main()
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://webapi.coinfloor.co.uk:8090/bist/XBT/GBP/balance/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "userID/apikey", "passphrase"))));

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                   new KeyValuePair<string, string>("User ID","userid"),
                   new KeyValuePair<string, string>("API key","apikey"),
                   new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Passphrase","pass")
                   
                });
        try
        {
           
               var result = await client.PostAsync("https://webapi.coinfloor.co.uk:8090/bist/XBT/GBP/balance/", content);
               string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         }
```

I've tried using both the default authorization headers and sending the data with `FormUrlEncodedContent`. their [documentation](https://github.com/coinfloor/API/blob/master/BIST.md) says:

> " All private API calls require authentication. You need to provide 3 parameters to authenticate a request: User ID, API key, Passphrase"

Not sure what I'm doing wrong,
and how should I be sending other extra parameters in the requests?

Comment: Won't hurt to look at your request in fiddler and ensure it looks like expected.

Comment: Are you sending the actual values for user Id, api key and passphrase or the string values "userID/apikey" and "passphrase"?

Comment: Thanks Tobias and Evk, I do have the right values in the code, just edited for this post. trying to figure out what the correct request should look like, in fliddler under request headers I see the standard headers plus an additional string with the values from FormUrlEncodedContent which seem correct to me

Answer (score 0):

just a note to mention that the code is actually correct, there was a mistake on my part with the various ids and passwords.